# Allocating memory for array in struct (in C)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

I need to define a type-struct in C that contains an array to be malloc'd as:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct mine
{
    int N;
    double *A;
} mine;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int i;
    mine *m=malloc(sizeof(mine));
    printf("sizeof(mine)=%d\n",sizeof(mine));
    scanf("Enter array size: %d",&(m->N));
    m->A=malloc((m->N)*sizeof(double));
    for(i=0; i < m->N; i++)
        m->A[i]=i+0.23;
    printf("First array element: %lf",m->A[0]);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The program compiles and runs, and the integer assignment seems to work fine. The array is not working as it should, however.

Any suggestions? I would like *m* to remain a pointer (to pass to functions etc.).

Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem with the array? (i.e. what output do you get, and what do you want?)

Comment: What does "not working as it should" mean?

Comment: Stylistic and safety sidenotes: 1. `malloc(sizeof(mine));`  - rather `malloc(sizeof(*m));`; 2. `&(m->N)` - try `&m->N` instead; 3. `printf("sizeof(mine)=%d\n",sizeof(mine));` is UB, use the `%zu` format specifier and look up what's they type of the value `sizeof()` yields; 4. `m->A=malloc((m->N)*sizeof(double));` - some whitespace, readability and safety doesn't hurt, write `m->A = malloc(m->N * sizeof(m->A[0]));` instead.

Comment: `scanf` doesn't take a "prompt" string. Always check it's return value before using its outputs!

Comment: @H2CO3 All of those comments are pretty much related to subjective coding style... only the %d with sizeof is a problem in theory. In practice, very few (if any) compilers implement size_t as anything else but `unsigned int`.

Comment: @H2CO3: I could argue that `sizeof(*m)` is safer than `sizeof(mine))` in case decide to change the type of `m` from `mine` to `yours`.

Comment: @Lundin 1. Not quite - if the type of the object changes, and the programmer forgets to change the type within the `sizeof()` operator, there will problems writing to unallocated memory (redundancy is bad, isn't it?) 2. I've seen `unsigned int` as well as `unsigned long` - both of them invoke undefined behavior when printed using `%d` which is for `int`. Signedness matters. **Size matters.**

Comment: @NikBougalis Exactly.

Comment: @H2CO3 never mind, haven't had morning coffee yet ;)

Comment: I can't bother to have the `malloc(sizeof(*array))` vs `malloc(sizeof(type))` debate yet again. That debate is frequent enough to show that there is no consensus among programmers for either style, both forms have minor drawbacks. I have never encountered bugs using either style, so I consider the whole thing a non-issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
scanf("Enter array size: %d",&(m->N));
```

It should be two separate steps:

```
printf("Enter array size: ");
scanf("%d",&(m->N));
```

(and for debugging checking:)

```
printf("The size entered appears to be %d\n", m->N);
```

That way, you know if you got the value you intended to get!

Comment: +1 It is worth mentioning to check the result of `scanf()` to ensure an assignment was made (in this case that an `int` was read and assigned to `m->N`).

Answer (score 0):

If @abelenky answered your question fine, but I was always told to cast the results of malloc from the void * it returns into whatever you are actually working with.

```
mine *m = (mine *)malloc(sizeof(mine));
```

Comment: In C, unlike C++, you don't have to cast the resulting pointer from *malloc*. And I usually don't cast when it is not necessary, as that may hide another problem.

Comment: I've always seen mixed feelings on the cast, so I usually let it be. Thanks, though.

Comment: No problem. I didn't know the difference between the C and C++ specs, but learned C++ first which is probably why I still cast it. Thanks for pointing that out.